# Embedding a Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, iframe

I have embedded a Google Map in my website. I want to change its location according to user input. How can I do this?

I tried to copy the link of the location and assign it to the `iframe` `src`:

```
    $("iframe").attr("src", "https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=USA&hl=en&ll=37.09024,-95.712891&spn=131.016476,346.289063&sll=23.259933,77.412615&sspn=0.178842,0.338173&oq=usa&doflg=ptm&hnear=United+States&t=m&z=2");
```

but the `iframe` is not loading the map.

Comment: what all input you are retrieving from user ( is it latitude and longitude )?

Comment: Can you provide the html? the jQuery part is correct, so the only error could be in your HTML unless the selector is wrong, but we cant see that without your source.

Comment: Do you have google map api key ?

Comment: V3 doesn't need api key.

Comment: If you have google map api key you can do it ver fantastically :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>  
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Initiate map 
function initialize(data) { 
  // Make position for center map 
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lng, data.lat); 

  // Map options  
  var myOptions = { 
    zoom: 10, 
    center: myLatLng, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID 
  }; 

  // Initiate map 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

  // Info window element 
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

  // Set pin 
  setPin(data); 
} 
// Show position 
function setPin(data) { 
  var pinLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lng, data.lat); 
  var pinMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: pinLatLng, 
    map: map, 
    data: data 
  }); 

  // Listen for click event  
  google.maps.event.addListener(pinMarker, 'click', function() { 
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pinMarker.position.lat(), pinMarker.position.lng())); 
    map.setZoom(18); 
    onItemClick(event, pinMarker); 
  }); 
} 
// Info window trigger function 
function onItemClick(event, pin) { 
  // Create content  
  var contentString = pin.data.text + "<br /><br /><hr />Coordinate: " + pin.data.lng +"," + pin.data.lat; 

  // Replace our Info Window's content and position 
  infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
  infowindow.setPosition(pin.position); 
  infowindow.open(map) 
} 
</script>  
</head>  
<body onload="initialize({lat:-3.19332,lng:55.952366,text:'<h2>Edinburgh</h2><i>Nice city!</i>'})"> 
  <div id="map_canvas">  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the [GoogleMaps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). The offer way more control (geocode, searching, custom marker, etc...) over the map then just embedding a iframe.